# Swift Closure Issue

Tags: swift, firebase, closures, firebase-realtime-database

Im just hacking away in Swift but for the life of me I can't get this to `return` anything but an empty `[Item]`.  The `[Item]` is correct and the way I want it if I execute the `print` function inside the closure.

```
func getCurrentDetails(ref: FIRDatabaseReference) -> [Item] {
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var currentDetails = [Item]()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            var currentItem = Item(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            if currentItem.Name != "" { 
                currentItem.Image = "http://www.deletedthisurl/" + currentItem.Number + "_500X500.gif"
                currentDetails.append(currentItem)   
            }   
        }
        self.currentArray = currentDetails
        // print(self.currentArray)  // Prints here
    })
    print(self.currentArray)  //Prints an empty Item array here
    return currentArray
}
```

Comment: Possibly a concurrency issue.  Declaring the block isn't the same as executing it.  Most likely your print statement is happening before the block code is even run.

Comment: Hmm.   The self.currentArray that prints reflects the changes in the closure body..

Comment: Ahhh.. I understand now.

Comment: In general, don't think of Firebase events as functions. t's usually better not to treat them as such (i.e. don't try to return value as that's not what they are for). For example, loading an array to populate a tableView: Iterate over the snapshot with *for child in snapshot.children{}* and then inside that for-loop work with each child - adding data to an array for example. Then when the loop is completed, call  tableView.reloadData(). Keep all of that code within the block. If you want to do something with the array data after it's populated, call the next step from *within the block.*

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to return the value since the call to firebase is assync.

To handle it you can use a completion handler.

```
func getCurrentDetails(ref: FIRDatabaseReference, completion:(currentArray:[Item])->()) {
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var currentDetails = [Item]()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            var currentItem = Item(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            if currentItem.Name != "" { 
                currentItem.Image = "http://www.deletedthisurl/" +
                    currentItem.Number + "_500X500.gif"
                currentDetails.append(currentItem)   
            }   
        }
        self.currentArray = currentDetails
        completion(currentArray)
    })
}
```

When calling you should do as the following:

```
var newVar
getCurrentDetails(ref) { (currentArray) in
    newVar = currentArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try that if I run into any issues.  I wound up just writing another function and passing self.currentArray in as an argument.

Comment: @TM Right, but I'm sure that with my answer you can get the array when calling the function :)

Comment: By populating the class array *self.array* within the block, it's populated by the time the block is completing so there's no need to also pass it into the completion handler as it's already populated.

Comment: @Jay For sure jay, but since his intention was to return it when calling the method I focused on giving help on doing it. Don't know exactly his use case.

Comment: So is there a way to return the currentArray from the getCurrentDetails function?   var test = getCurrentDetails(ref) {(currentArray in print(CurrentArray)} ?

Comment: @TM yes, there is. And thats exactly what my answer is explaining how to :) let me know if you couldtn undertand anything

Comment: Thanks for your help.   I can't seem to figure out how to simply create a new variable with the return value.  (don't want to print currentArray, just want to store it as a different variable)

Comment: @TM then just replace the print call with `var newVar = currentArray`

Comment: @TM the point is that, where you would call `var newVar = getCurrentDetails(ref)` you need to go with `getCurrentDetails(..... {var newVar = currentArray}`

Comment: var newVar = getCurrentDetails(ref) {var newVar = currentArray}  ?

Comment: @TM  then initialize it out of the function call... `var newVar     getCurrentDetails(..... {newVar = currentArray}`

Comment: print(newVar) = []  outside of the getCurrentDetails func